# Dynamically changing Excel cell value based on active sheet's name

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 sheets in the Excel file, the sheet names are `Main`, `Production`, `Outflow`, `Inflow`, `Options`.

Is there a way I can set up a formula in the `Options` sheet to reference the name of the sheet I'm currently viewing?

So if I'm viewing the Production sheet it'll put Production in A1 of the Option sheet, then if I click to view the Outflow sheet it'll change the A1 in the Option sheet to show Outflow.

Tried searching but couldn't find anything like this anywhere. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Easy enough, but what happens when you view `Options`?

Comment: @BK201 still works as the local sheet can have the its own sheet name in a formula

Comment: @brettdj: Fair enough. However, I think OP is using A1 in `Options` sheet as a reference for data he wants to show. Maybe using it in an `INDIRECT` formula. Anyway, posting an answer.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this on a sheet level rather than in vba? I am currently using vba script do make this change, but keep running into a debugging error stating that the sheet is locked. I have added a function to unlock the sheet when it is activated in order to change the cell content, but the error still occurs. I think this could go away if the cell can be dynamically changed on the sheet level itself without VBA script changing it. Is there a cell formula like `=ActiveSheet.name` or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want anything to happen if `Options` is selected, the following subroutine should work:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name <> "Options" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Options").Range("A1") = Sh.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to still show `Options` when `Options` sheet is selected, just remove the `IF-THEN` block. :)

Make sure to copy and paste the above to the `ThisWorkbook` code area.

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the `ThiwWorkbook` module add

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Sheets("Options").[a1] = Sh.Name
End Sub
```

Which will put the current sheet name in cell `A1` of a sheet called *Options*